# IOS UIWebView and Safari is not sending If-None-Match but Android WebView and Chrome does

Tags: android, iphone, asp.net, http, safari

I am using ASP.NET as server of IOS and Android, which uses ETag and If-None-Match header to return 304 or 200. When I check this on Chrome Dev Tool and remote Debug Android WebView every things works means he is sending If-None-Match request header. But doing the same in Safari and remote debug IOS UIWebView always not send If-None-Match header. Is If-None-Match header not work in IOS. Same result in Safari

**Edit:** Here are the Response Headers in Safari,

```
Cache-Control:private
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:448
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 19 Jun 2013 09:27:46 GMT
Etag:00amyWGct0y_ze4lIsj2Mw
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://books.google.ae/books?id=59ltM_nz048C&pg=RA3-PA15&lpg=RA3-PA15&dq=%22Safari%22%20%22ETAGS%22&source=bl&ots=mkuoueMByV&sig=ZFMp57JqUP76-RWoBNL_t61lF0k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YLPBUb6oDo7yrQfk3IHIDQ&ved=0CE8Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22Safari%22%20%22ETAGS%22&f=false),

> Caution A few years ago, ETags were used mostly by proxies and not as much by browsers. The value of ETags slowly grows because of the increasing support by browsers. Keep in mind that not all browsers support ETags, though. For example, Apple's Safari does not support them. You may consider providing Last-Modified headers as well and checking for If-Modified-Since headers in addition to using ETags if you expect  a large number of of Safari users to visit your site

Comment: That sounds VERY VERY misleading. ETags have been supported for a very long time.

Comment: Means book quite is wrong. PLease test it with your machine and send me a sample response header with ETag that work for you.

Comment: @JulianReschke You can install this and check

Answer (score 0):

Your ETag header field value in syntactically incorrect. Maybe that's why Safari ignores it (which would be good!).

Another reason might be the inability to handle "Vary" correctly (this definitively affects some versions of IE).

Comment: Do you test a sample in Safari and let me know if ETags work in Safari. See my answer which is saying that Safari does not implement ETags.

Comment: I don't have a current Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Check this chart to determine if its version specific problem

http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/06/28/mobile-browser-cache-limits/